# Java ResultSet in BlockingQueue

Tags: java

I trying to write some blob from database to disk by passing an InputStream object to the queue. It creates the file with size 0. When I have tried write the InputStream to the disk without using a BlockingQueue, it worked without problem.
Can you help me?
My code is like below:

```
public class ExtractPicture implements Runnable{
    private BlockingQueue<InputStream> queue;
    public ExtractPicture(BlockingQueue<InputStream> queue){
        this.queue = queue;
    }    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try(Connection conn = new DatabaseConnection().getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select mypicture from testpicture")){            
            while(rs.next()){
                queue.put(rs.getBinaryStream("mypicture"));
            }  
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
class Consumer implements Runnable{
    private BlockingQueue<InputStream> queue;
    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<InputStream> queue){
        this.queue = queue;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{            
            int z = 0;
            InputStream is = null;
//            (is = queue.take()) != null
            while((is = queue.take()) != null){                
                System.out.println("consumer aa" + is.toString());
                writeToDisk(is, "c:\\temp\\p" + z + ".jpeg");
                z++;
            }
            is.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
   private void writeToDisk(InputStream is, String fna){
       OutputStream f = null;
        try {
            f = new FileOutputStream(new File(fna));
            int c = 0;
            while((c = is.read()) > -1){
                f.write(c);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        } finally {
            try {
                f.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
   }
}
class RunService{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        BlockingQueue<InputStream> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(10);
        ExtractPicture ep = new ExtractPicture(queue);
        Consumer c = new Consumer(queue);
        new Thread(ep).start();
        new Thread(c).start();
    }    
}
```

Comment: how many entries of blob are there in your table and how many gets written?

Comment: there are 3 records in my table

Comment: and how many gets persisted?

Comment: what do you mean? I have 3 rows in my table, the column is blob type and is filled with 3 images one for each row.

Answer (score 0):

When your producer exits from the `run` method, it closes all the resources, including the `ResultSet` that's backing the `InputStream`.
So, by the time `Consumer` gets to it, there is nothing to read.

Comment: I have tried to use an Integer instead of InputStream and worked without problem. what should I change?

Comment: You have to read the stream before it is closed. It does not make much sense to do it on a separate thread anyway.  Get rid of the queue, and do `writeToDisk` write where you get the stream from result set.

Comment: Also, do not swallow exceptions like this: `catch (IOException ex) {}`. It is a very bad habit. Like, in this case, you would probably not need to post questions on SO to find out what is going on, if you saw that attempting to read from your stream throws an exception, that says stream is closed, right?

Comment: yes you are right, the connection is closed. just for curiosity is it possible to do it as I have tried? I know that I can write by escaping the queue.